# While restarting stopwatch there's a slight difference in saved time and elapsed time

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

[image]

```
     private void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //  Stopwatch Start
{
    timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(MyMethod), TimerDisplay, 0, 1);
    timer2 = new Timer(new TimerCallback(MyMethod_Current), CurrentTimerDisplay, 0, 1);
    stopwatch.Start();
    currentStopwatch.Start();
}

private async void MyMethod(object Displayblock)
{
    ms = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    TextBlock Bd = (TextBlock)Displayblock;
    ss = ms / 1000; ms = ms % 1000;
    mm = ss / 60; ss = ss % 60;
    hh = mm / 60; mm = mm % 60;
    dd = hh / 24; hh = hh % 24;
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => { Bd.Text = dd.ToString("00") + ":" + hh.ToString("00") + ":" + mm.ToString("00") + ":" + ss.ToString("00") + ":" + ms.ToString("000"); });

}

private async void MyMethod_Current(object Displayblock1)
{
    ms1 = currentStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    TextBlock Bd1 = (TextBlock)Displayblock1;
    ss1 = ms1 / 1000; ms1 = ms1 % 1000;
    mm1 = ss1 / 60; ss1 = ss1 % 60;
    hh1 = mm1 / 60; mm1 = mm1 % 60;
    dd1 = hh1 / 24; hh1 = hh1 % 24;
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => { Bd1.Text = dd1.ToString("00") + ":" + hh1.ToString("00") + ":" + mm1.ToString("00") + ":" + ss1.ToString("00") + ":" + ms1.ToString("000"); });

}

private void AppBarButton_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // Add Lap
{
    if(LapStore.Text=="")
    {
        currentStopwatch.Restart(); // when I restart the second timer and pause theres a slight difference of milli seconds
        Lap_Count++;
        LapStore.Text += ("Lap" + " " + Lap_Count).ToString();
        LapStore.Text += ("\n" + TimerDisplay.Text + "\n").ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        currentStopwatch.Restart();
        Lap_Count++;
        LapStore.Text += ("Lap" + " " + Lap_Count).ToString();
        LapStore.Text += ("\n" + CurrentTimerDisplay.Text + "\n").ToString();
    }
}
```

I want no difference when I restart the second timer. What is the possible solution to avoid this because when I add a lap and pause the stopwatch and calculate theres a difference in milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**:
I think the missing time is from the delay between your UI updates and the button event. You should take the time in the button event:

```
private void AppBarButton_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // Add Lap
{
    var elapsed = currentStopwatch.Elapsed;
    currentStopwatch.Restart();
    Lap_Count++;
    LapStore.Text += ("Lap" + " " + Lap_Count).ToString();
    LapStore.Text += ("\n" + elapsed.ToString("G") + "\n").ToString();
}
```

---

That behaviour is correct IMO:

1. You press the "lap-button" at x.123 seconds
2. `currentStopwatch` is resetted
3. `currentStopwatch` continues at 0.000 seconds, but `stopwatch` still continues at x.123 seconds

=> there is an "offset" of 123 ms.

P.S.: Why are you calculating this on your own, why not simply:

```
elapsed = stopwatch.Elapsed;
ms = elapsed.Milliseconds;
ss = elapsed.Seconds;
mm = elapsed.Minutes;
hh = elapsed.Hours;
dd = elapsed.Days;
```

Comment: @shriyanshk: Again: It **IS** correct. Why would you want to make it "incorrect" just to "look better"?

Comment: yes because for example if I add up the time in Lap counts it shows the difference that's why I think to correct it. I have uploaded a picture to show why it feels wrong

Comment: @shriyanshk: Ok, now I get your actual problem. You should write that clearly in your question. The sum of the 3 laps are 25 ms less as the total time.

Comment: Actually its not fixed to 25 ms sometimes its less than 25 ms and greater than 25 ms also

Comment: it works but one problem when I add Laps the milliseconds figure comes in 7 digits instead of 3

Comment: @shriyanshk: Just use the format string you like instead of "G", see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Got it. Works fine but when I add up all laps  milliseconds shows a difference of 001

Comment: @shriyanshk: Add up the full resolution (not only the 3 digits) and it should  fit as I guess thats just rounding inaccuracy...